# union and rollup in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union, rollup

I couldn't find what is causing this error, when I union headers with the actual data constructed using rollup to write them to a .csv file.

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` int(11) default NULL,
`item` varchar(100) default NULL,
`value` int(11) default NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM ;

INSERT INTO `products` VALUES (1,'Mobiles', '1000'),(5,'Mobiles', '2000'),(8,'Mobiles', 4000),(18,'Books',100),(28,'Books', 200),(28,'Books',400);
```

When I try the below query,

```
 SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT 'ITEM', 'SUM')
    UNION
    (select item, sum(value) from products group by item with rollup)
) data;
```

I get this error

```
ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 'ITEM', 'SUM'
union
select item, sum(value) from products group by item with rollup
;
```

Result:

```
+---------+------+
| ITEM    | SUM  |
+---------+------+
| ITEM    | SUM  |
| Books   | 700  |
| Mobiles | 7000 |
| NULL    | 7700 |
+---------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks Vladmir! This is exactly what I wanted. But I don't get, how the query I've given doesn't work, which actually does the same thing except separating the single query into sub-queries by using brackets. Any insights ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use this way.

You need to do either

```
select item, sum(value) from products group by item with rollup;
```

or

```
select item, sum(value) as tot from products group by item
union all
select 'ITEM',sum(value) from products
```

The result of first query will be as

```
+---------+------------+
| item    | sum(value) |
+---------+------------+
| Books   |        700 |
| Mobiles |       7000 |
| NULL    |       7700 |
+---------+------------+
```

and the 2nd

```
+---------+------+
| item    | tot  |
+---------+------+
| Books   |  700 |
| Mobiles | 7000 |
| ITEM    | 7700 |
+---------+------+
```

Comment: You can combine both approaches this way: `SELECT  IFNULL(item, 'TOTAL') AS item, SUM(value) AS tot FROM products GROUP BY item WITH ROLLUP;`

Answer (score 0):

you could use this

```
 SELECT * FROM ( select item as 'ITEM', sum(value) as 'SUM'
              from products group by item with rollup) as data
```